# Split array in groups with percentages

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to split array users in 3 groups with 3 percentage: 34%, 33% and 33%.
Here is my code:

```
var percentages = [34, 33, 33];
var index = 0;
var groups = [];
for (let i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
    let numUsers = Math.floor((percentages[i] * users.length) / 100);
    var newGroup= [];
       
    for (let j = 0; j < numUsers; j++){
        newGroup.push(users[index]);
        index++;
    }
    groups.push(newGroup);
}
```

The problem is that array users is wrong. Here is my result:

```
[
  ["user1","user2","user3"],
  ["user4","user5","user6"],
  ["user7","user8","user9"]
]
```

I want this :

```
[
  ["user1","user2","user3", "user4"],
  ["user5","user6","user7"],
  ["user8","user9","user10"]
]
```

The "user4" must be in first group

Help pls

Comment: please add the missing data and the output you get.

Comment: What output do you expect if your percentages would be this: `[34, 32, 34]` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first find out how many units (users) can at least be distributed without exceeding the percentages. Then check how many units are remaining to distribute, and distribute them to the slots where the remaining, unused percentage is greatest.

Here is how that can be done. Comments should clarify each step:

```js
function groupByPercentage(users, percentages) {
  // Get percentage for 1 user:
  let unit = 100 / users.length;
  // Sort percentages by decreasing remainder (modulo unit) 
  //   and get number of units covered by each percentage
  let sorted = percentages.map((p, i) => [i, Math.floor(p / unit), p % unit])
                          .sort((a, b) => b[2] - a[2]);
  // Get how many units are not yet distributed:
  let remain = users.length - sorted.reduce((sum, a) => sum += a[1], 0);
  // Distribute those, giving priority to groups where the remainders are greatest
  for (let i = 0; i < remain; i++) sorted[i][1]++;
  // Build and return the chunks by filling the groups in their 
  //    original order
  let i = 0;
  return sorted.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]).map(a => users.slice(i, i+=a[1]));
}

// Demo
let percentages = [34, 33, 33];
let users = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"];
let result = groupByPercentage(users, percentages);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below works. The problem is that when you have a list of 11 users. In this case first array would have 5 users and last two arrays would have 3 users. Don't know what is expected so I didn't try to guess :)

```js
var users = [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

var percentages = [34, 33, 33];

var usersPerGroup = Math.round(users.length / percentages.length);

var biggestGroup = Math.max(...percentages);

var extraUsers = users.length;

for (let i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
    let numUsers = Math.round((percentages[i] * users.length) / 100);
    extraUsers -= numUsers;
}

var index = 0;
var groups = [];
for (let i = 0; i < percentages.length; i++) {
    let numUsers = Math.round((percentages[i] * users.length) / 100);
    if (extraUsers > 0 && percentages[i] === biggestGroup) {
        numUsers += extraUsers;
    }
    var newGroup= [];

    for (let j = 0; j < numUsers; j++){
        newGroup.push(users[index]);
        index++;
    }
    groups.push(newGroup);
}

console.log(groups)
```

Comment: I tried with 10 users, and [80, 10, 10] as percentages. The result had 9 values in the first array, 1 in the second and an undefined value in the last output array. I also tried with 4 users and [60, 20, 20] as percentages. The fourth user was not in the output. Seems not to work consistently...

Comment: @trincot, you are right. Modified it a little bit so this [80, 10, 10] for 10 users works. About [60, 20, 20] and 4 users I don't know what is a expected result, so it's difficult to write a code based on that. Because what is? First array 2 users, second and third 1 user? Or [3, 1, 0]? The code above creates now an array [4, 0, 0]. Nevertheless, thanks for a comment. Could play with it a little bit more :P There is still some code duplication that I don't like but unfortunately I don't know how to solve it. If you have some ideas that would be great ;)

Comment: That fixes the anomalies with `undefined` and non-distributed users. Still, when I input 3 users, with percentages [34, 33, 33], then all three users end up in the first array. So the code actually generates a distribution of [100%, 0, 0], while [1,1,1] = [33.33%, 33.33%, 33.33%] is much closer to the target. Indeed, it depends on what the OP expects in these cases. I understood they want to minimise the differences between the *achieved* percentages and the *targeted* percentages.

Comment: Yeah, instead of Math.floor() now is Math.round() which works much better. Thanks ;) If you have some other scenarios please let me know, it's nice to look for some solutions ;D